Why can't I install version 2.0.1 of KivyMD module?
I followed all the possible instructions to install the new version (from pip, from zip, from commit hash), and it really seem working, considering the successful output. But when i run my files, the console prints this message:
[KivyMD] Version 1.2.0 is deprecated and is no longer supported. Use KivyMD version 2.0.0 from the master branch (pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip)
It's not only a message but i can't import all the new elements that come with the version 2.0.1, it shows me only the ones provided in 1.2.0.
I'm feeling a bit stupid. Can someone help me?
I tried all the possible ways to install this branch (from pip, from zip, from commit hash), but i only get the 1.2.0.

Do you have the dependencies installed? See the webpage?

It's because the KivyMD developers can't solve their bug. I would recommend you to stay with 1.2.0. I'm using it right now and was a little bit confused, but it still can handle my task. You can find the bug about installation with KivyMD 2.0.

According to https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/#installation:
pip install kivymd/KivyMD

Also you can install manually from sources. Just clone the project and run pip:
git clone https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git --depth 1
cd KivyMD
pip install .

I noticed you can install direct from their github because it isn't recognized via Pypi.
!Latest version there is 1.2.0 and they released the 2.0.1 version:]1
